# How to manage utility pods on GKE autopilot?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My company is going to migrate to GCP, and I found some issues with how we want to manage our infrastructure and projects.

Our stack is mainly based on Kubernetes, right now we have 2 clusters:

- production
- dev/test

In each cluster, we have deployed many tools such as:

- externalDNS (our nameservers are managed by CloudFlare)
- cert-manager
- ingress-controller
- other useful tools such as sealed-secrets...

In our previous organization we had many different apps on each cluster separated in different namespaces but now we might want to use GKE Autopilot to maybe have 1 cluster per app (not sure but we will surely have more clusters).
Since GKE Autopilot is pay per pod and ressources, if I deploy externalDNS on all clusters I will pay for each pod which can lead to a bump in billing with no added "business value".

Is there a way to:

- have more finegrained clusters with Autopilot
- without having to pay for tooling pods on each of the clusters?

Anyone has recommendations on how to manage the clusters?
Maybe having 1 cluster per app is overkill?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with multiple clusters?

Comment: I want to have a better separation between apps, but maybe i will just use Google Cloud Run after looking for the different container services. It's just that we have everything deployed using helm, so the migration was quite straightforward with k8s

Comment: If you can use Cloud Run, then definitely give it a go.
If you are still interested in using GKE Autopilot, one way to separate different workloads would be to use a combination of namespaces and workload separation ( https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#workload_separation ).  With workload separation, you end up with workloads on different sets of nodes behind the scenes.